# Dependency conflict: Installing libgd3:i386 leads to removal of important packages?

Tags: package-management, 22.04, wine

I want to install wine by following the instructions on the winehq.org website. when I follow the instructions it turns out that I need the libgd3:i386 package, and when I try to install it turns out that it will delete some packages / software

```
sudo apt install libgd3:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  acl apg colord-data fonts-wine gnome-control-center-faces gnome-online-accounts hplip-data
  libavif13 libcapi20-3 libcolord-gtk1 libcolorhug2 libfaudio0 libgav1-0 libgphoto2-l10n
  libgsound0 libgupnp-av-1.0-3 libgupnp-dlna-2.0-4 libhpmud0 libieee1284-3 libimagequant0
  libldb2 libnfs13 libodbc2 libraqm0 librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2
  librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2 libsane-common libsane-hpaio libsmbclient
  libsnmp-base libsnmp40 libstb0 libtalloc2 libtevent0 libvkd3d-shader1 libvkd3d1
  libwbclient0 libyuv0 libz-mingw-w64 mobile-broadband-provider-info network-manager-gnome
  printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-postscript-hp python3-ldb python3-macaroonbakery
  python3-olefile python3-pil python3-protobuf python3-pymacaroons python3-renderpm
  python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel python3-rfc3339 python3-talloc python3-tz rygel
  samba-libs sane-airscan shotwell-common vkd3d-compiler
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libbrotli1:i386 libbsd0:i386 libdeflate0:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfontconfig1:i386
  libfreetype6:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libmd0:i386
  libpng16-16:i386 libtiff5:i386 libwebp7:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386
  libxdmcp6:i386 libxpm4:i386
Suggested packages:
  libgd-tools:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  colord gnome-control-center gvfs-backends hplip libc-devtools libgd3 libgphoto2-6 libsane1
  libwine sane-utils shotwell simple-scan ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal wine wine64
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libbrotli1:i386 libbsd0:i386 libdeflate0:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfontconfig1:i386
  libfreetype6:i386 libgd3:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libmd0:i386
  libpng16-16:i386 libtiff5:i386 libwebp7:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386
  libxdmcp6:i386 libxpm4:i386
0 upgraded, 19 newly installed, 16 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 890 kB/2.835 kB of archives.
After this operation, 585 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

do I have to worry when the packages/software are deleted.

I'm open to any suggestions or alternative approaches.

Comment: You are wise to ask. Approving that change will, as you suspect, remove large slabs of your system.

Comment: Problem 1: `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required` big list needs to be reviewed by you. Read that list, package by package. Decide which (if any) you want to keep. Use `sudo apt install <packagename>` to mark the ones to keep, `sudo apt autoremove` the rest.

Comment: Problem 2: Your output clearly shows that you already have a `wine` package installed. Clean up before re-installing from a different source. That means uninstalling your current wine and all dependencies.

Comment: Since you already have Wine installed, why do you want a different non-Ubuntu version that seems to break your system? Is something wrong with the current version that's already installed?

Comment: first of all I don't have wine in my current system. the reason why I want to install these packages is because when I want to install winehq-stable it needs wine-stable and when I try to install wine-stable it needs libgd3:i386.

Comment: It's right there in your output: `The following packages will be REMOVED:` includes `wine`. You must uninstall that package, and its dependencies, in order to install Wine-hq packages.